# gnat binder output file

Tags: gnat

I would like to know more about the "version numbers" created by GNAT in the binder output file. They look something like this:

```
   --  The following set of constants give the version
   --  identification values for every unit in the bound
   --  partition. This identification is computed from all
   --  dependent semantic units, and corresponds to the
   --  string that would be returned by use of the
   --  Body_Version or Version attributes.

   --  The following Export pragmas export the version numbers
   --  with symbolic names ending in B (for body) or S
   --  (for spec) so that they can be located in a link. The
   --  information provided here is sufficient to track down
   --  the exact versions of units used in a given build.

   type Version_32 is mod 2 ** 32;
   u00001 : constant Version_32 := 16#8ad6e54a#;
   pragma Export (C, u00001, "helloB");
   u00002 : constant Version_32 := 16#fbff4c67#;
   pragma Export (C, u00002, "system__standard_libraryB");
   u00003 : constant Version_32 := 16#1ec6fd90#;
   pragma Export (C, u00003, "system__standard_libraryS");
```

Sometime these constants terminate with 'B' or 'S' which I assume they stand for Body and Spec.

I would like to know why they exist in the first place and when and how they are used. I couldn't find any option to gnat that will enforce these checks.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

They are used to track dependencies.

If you change a spec file, both the appropriate body and anything "with"ing that spec must be recompiled to keep the final executable consistent.

Unlike C and friends, which requires you to track all this by writing a correct Makefile this mechanism detects and corrects changes in your program's dependencies, usually by forcing recompilation of anything necessary.

(Sometimes, e.g. when some of the necessary files can't be compiled thanks to file permissions, you'll get a `file xxx out of date because yyy changed, recompile xxx` message).

Last time I looked, Gnu Make's manual was about 340 pages long - and should properly be included in language size/complexity comparisons, as part of the knowledge you need to successfully work in C.

I'm not surprised you can't find a Gnat option for this.

**There shouldn't be an option to NOT enforce these checks; I can't see any use case where it makes sense to build internally inconsistent executables.**

This probably isn't the answer you are looking for. You are asking low level questions about implementation details, without context. Perhaps a better question would explain what you are trying to achieve, and what is missing in the Gnat documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why are they presented in the final object code if these constants are only used to track dependencies compile-time? This is something which I totally don't understand.

Comment: That I can't answer, only guess. It may simply be because they are in the (binding) source code; (there may be ways of stripping them; I didn't see any in the 200-ish byte executables I was generating with custom RTS for bare metal MCUs). Or they may have a role in dynamic linking (.so or .dll) though I think that's unlikely.

Comment: actually then the binder detects this, it's too late to recompile the sources. You just get a "unit xxx must be recompiled" message, and you have to manually delete the objects to do so. Sometimes happens when 2 files have the same timestamp, or compiler was changed without recompilation occurring...